# Optimum way of charging apple devices?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, ipad, battery, charging

I have recently read the article [Should you leave your smartphone plugged into the charger overnight?](http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/expert-advice-on-how-to-avoid-destroying-your-phones-battery/)

**The article listed the following points:**

> You can leave your phone plugged into the charger overnight without
>   too much risk, provided it’s not a counterfeit charger, and you don’t
>   let your phone overheat. For best results with your smartphone
>   charging, here’s what to remember:
>
> - Always use official chargers and cables, or certified alternatives from reputable brands and retailers.
> - Don’t let your phone get too hot. Remove the case when charging overnight.
> - For the longest battery life possible, try to keep your battery between 50 and 80 percent.
> - Avoid letting phone battery completely discharge, and don’t charge it from 0 percent up to 100 percent too often.

---

**Is this actually the optimum way of charging iPhones, iPads, MacBooks ?**

Comment: Well, this is true: "Always use official chargers and cables, or certified alternatives from reputable brands and retailers." Everything else is, at best, debatable.

Answer (score 1):

That article is focusing on the possible dangers of starting a fire if not original components are used.

Now you can ignore it and continue using non apple hardware at your own risk (usually small but it can happen), or use OEM hardware that is designed to prevent overheating (over-current) and it will shut down before serious stuff occurs.

Definitely do not put it under your pillow while charging or in any case allowing it to radiate the heat generated.

The points 2, 3, and 4 are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's always best to go straight to the source: http://www.apple.com/batteries/

There are a lot of myths that come with batteries. It used to be the case that you shouldn't charge a device until it was completely discharged—that the more you drain to 0%, the better it is on the battery. In reality, there are all sorts of strange theories, but if you follow what is on Apple's site, you should be guaranteed to have optimal operation.

Answer (score -1):

Pro-tip: Use an iPad charger on your iPhone and it will fill up 2x as fast.